# What are some of the public solana nodes I can connect to for my solana application?

Tags: development, node

What are some of the public solana nodes I can connect to for development purposes? And is there a good rest api examples I can view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to any of the RPC nodes that are available for Solana:

- The standard Solana ones
- GenesysGo
- QuickNode
- Alchemy
- Triton

The actual URL you connect to varies whether you want to connect to Devnet, Testnest or Mainnet-Beta.

You can just do a web search for these providers and check their details.

Some of them are free, some are paid with a free tier, and some of them are paid with no free tier.

You won't use REST calls directly to connect, you want to use [@solana/web3.js](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/modules.html).